# Accessing variables created in "if __name__ == '__main__'" when importing a script as a module

Tags: python, python-3.x

From the below code, how can I access `futures` dictionary from script.py? If it wasn't contained within `if __name__ == '__main__':`, I could easily import the dictionary from another script, but now I'm unable to.

```
import pandas as pd
import concurrent.futures

files = ['1.xlsx','2.xlsx']

futures = {}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for filename in files:
            future = executor.submit(pd.read_excel, filename)
            futures[filename] = future
```

Comment: Move it out of `if __name__ == '__main__'`?

Comment: Unfortunately the `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()` always has to be called within a guard.

Comment: My way around this, was to just import the function, and call the function from within the main script's guard. Not sure if it's the best practice, but it works.